# Slack incoming webhook doesn't work if there are apostrophes in text

Tags: ruby, webhooks, slack

I have an incoming webhook on slack that acts as a notification system for changes in my ruby-based web-app (using Sinatra, not Rails).

Here's the code for the ruby method that sends the data to the webhook (sensitive info from the webhook_url is redacted as [...]):

```
def notify_slack(text, user)
    webhook_url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/[...]/[...]/[...]"
    payload = {
      :channel => "#app-changelog",
      :username => "Changelog Bot",
      :attachments => [
        {
          :fields => [
            {
              :title => "Change Description",
              :value => text
            },
            {
              :title => "Changed By:",
              :value => user,
              :short => true
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }.to_json
    cmd = "curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload=#{payload}' #{webhook_url}" 
    system(cmd) 
end
```

In the method, the `text` argument is a string that holds the description of the change and the `user` argument is a string that holds the name of the person responsible for the change.

However, if the `text` argument has an apostrophe `'` in it doesn't display anything on slack.

I've tried escaping the `'` in the `text` argument, but that didn't work - I've resorted to removing the apostrophes, but can't account for any situations where users may include apostrophes in anything. Plus according to slack's message builder, apostrophes should be possible.

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ one should check the `Kernel#system` call _return_. If it’s false, there is something wrong _with `curl` command itself_.

Comment: Why do you use a command line tool (curl) to make the HTTP request? Ruby comes with `Net::HTTP` and there are several HTTP gems out there.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the slack API call. The problem seems to be in this line:

```
"curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload=#{payload}' #{webhook_url}"
```

Note that you're using single quote to define limits for payload. So, in `payload`, if there is a single quote, it will become something like this:

```
"curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload=david's new bike' #{webhook_url}"
```

Now, you can observe that the payload should have ended with **bike**, but ends with **david**, and the extra text isn't valid for curl command.

You can try replacing single quotes with `\'`, and that should work.

```
payload=#{payload.gsub('\'', %q(\\\'))}
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed that! I'll try it out and let you know how it goes. But just so I understand, what does the `tr` method do here? I'm not too familiar with that method. Also, the `%q`? not too familiar with that either.

Comment: @UmarGhouse -- I replaced `tr` with `gsub` method, which replaces all the instances of a string with a new string. `%q` denotes a single quoted string, and is much convenient to use (otherwise, I would have used `'\\\\\''` instead).

Comment: Oh OK. Thanks for this. Unfortunately, I won't be able to test this for the next few days (on vacation :P). But I'll report back as soon as I do!